# Group Dates by month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by, sum

I've been working on this query and I'm about 90% where I need to be however there is one piece of this that I'm unable to figure out. Basically I'm looking for the Sum of Net flows by month, starting `12/31/2014` through the current date. I'm able to extract data by day and the sum of net flows for that day, however now I really need to be able to group all the dates in to their respective months. Ex. If I have `01/01/2015`, `01/02/2015` and `01/03/2015` I just want both of them to be grouped together and show up as `01/2015`. Bellow is the query that I have written. Please help with this last step.

```
SELECT
    DATE,
    SUM(NET_FLOWS/1000000.00) AS YTD_NET_FLOWS
FROM
    HISTORY_TBL
WHERE
    DATE >= TO_DATE ('12312014','MMDDYYYY')
GROUP BY
    DATE
ORDER BY
    DATE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can truncate a date to a given format (day, year, month, etc.), as shown here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084

```
SELECT TRUNC(DATE,'MM'), SUM(NET_FLOWS/1000000.00) AS YTD_NET_FLOWS
FROM HISTORY_TBL 
WHERE DATE >= TO_DATE ('12312014','MMDDYYYY') 
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATE,'MM') 
ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: @Michael.I added the TRUNC to my query and now I'm getting an ORA-00923: FROM Keyword not found where expected error and it underlined the SUM(NET_FLOWS/1000000.00) field. Any ideas as to why this error is popping up?

Comment: @Salman - TRUNC format masks are not like TO_CHAR masks - trunc()ing to the nearest month retains the year portion of the date

Comment: @ace123 - make sure you have the 'MM' in single quotes.as that error sounds like you missed closing a quote, or a bracket, or forgot the comma...

Comment: @Michael `SELECT TRUNC(DATE,'MM') SUM(NET_FLOWS/1000000.00) AS YTD_NET_FLOWS
FROM HISTORY_TBL1 
WHERE DATE >= TO_DATE ('12312014','MMDDYYYY')
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATE,'MM')
ORDER BY NAV_DATE` This is what I currently have. The quotes seem to be correct.

Comment: you've lost the comma after the close bracket of the TRUNC() in the select portion, so your two columns are not separated: SELECT TRUNC(DATE,'MM'), SUM(NET_FLOWS/1000000.00) AS YTD_NET_FLOWS FROM HISTORY_TBL1 WHERE DATE >= TO_DATE ('12312014','MMDDYYYY') GROUP BY TRUNC(DATE,'MM') ORDER BY NAV_DATE

Comment: @Michael, Thank you so much for your help, worked great. I really appreciate all your help with this.

Comment: No probs. You should also mark the answer as correct so that others don't waste time trying to solve a solved problem.